# How to raise error/warning when static_cast-ing values outside the set of enum class

Tags: c++, enums, casting, static-cast

Consider the case where I have to convert an `int` type to an `enum`. When doing this with `static_cast` the risk is that even values out of admissible values of the enum are casted. Take as example the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(char argc, char* argv[])
{
  enum class EnumType : uint8_t
  {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    default=255
  };

  EnumType enum_var;
  uint8_t num_var_out_of_range = 31;
  enum_var = static_cast<EnumType>(num_var_out_of_range);
  std::cout<<static_cast<int>(enum_var)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`31` is not in the set of the enum values. I guess that the cast is valid because the underlying type of the enum is able to represent that value, but in my opinion it would more appropriate to raise an error or warning in this case. Is there a way to manage such cases?

Comment: If all your enum values are consecutive (with no gaps) then you can also name two additional enumerators: minimum and maximum. For example, `enum class EnumType : uint8_t { A= 0, B = 1, minimum = A, maximum = B };`. Then you could check if the value to be converted belongs into that range, i.e., `if (num_var_out_of_range < static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(EnumType::minimum) || static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(EnumType::maximum) < num_var_out_of_range) throw std::out_of_range("enum value out of range");`.

Comment: * Sorry, a typo: `std::underlying_type_t<Enum>` is supposed to be `std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>` of course.

Comment: @heapunderrun Thanks for your tips, that's useful but I would like something to work in the most general case. To clarify that I have updated the question.

Comment: As we did not have reflection you simply have no chance. There is nothing in C++ which allows you to check against a set of enum values. Wait for C++43 :-) The discussions about reflection are ongoing for decades... and I did not see a chance for it if I follow this academic circle :-)

Comment: Well, if you really heavily utilize enums in you code, you could consider using some helper library, like the [Magic Enum C++](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) header-only library.